# Data duplication between two aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Two bounded contexts, implemented as microservices:

- **User Management**
- **Accounting**

The **User Management** hosts the aggregate `User` with its `Name`, `Email`, etc.

Some `User`s, on the other hand, become `Customer`s within the **Accounting** bounded context. The `Customer` has its own workflows, thereby it is an aggregate on its own. Its creation is triggered by the `UserRegistered` event (publish/subscribe mechanism).

In order to send an invoice, the **Accounting** needs the email address of the `Customer`. I'm wondering if the *email address* (whose data master is the `User`) should become part of the aggregate `Customer`, which would entail synchronizing each email address change of the `User`.

The other solution, which I'm inclined to consider cleaner, is to project the `email address` (and its changes) to a **readmodel** within the **Accounting**. Thus, the aggregate `Customer` is data master of its own state (e.g. payment workflow), but not the data already given by the `User`.

What do you think? Is data duplication between two aggregates, generally speaking, a bad thing to do?

Comment: I don't recommend it in CQRS. But why does the `Customer` Agg need the email address?

Comment: Martin Fowler have an answer for this: https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventCollaboration.html. Basically he says that data duplication is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think? Is data duplication between two aggregates, generally speaking, a bad thing to do?

No.  There is nothing wrong with having one "master" copy, owned by the authority of the data, and multiple subordinate copies.  When the authority is outside of your model altogether, then all of your copies might be subordinates to the real authority.

The duplicate copies of data support autonomy -- even though the master isn't currently available, other components in the system can continue to make progress using their local copies of the data.

You do want to have some care in your design -- the closer your capability is to the authority of the data it needs, the fewer problems you are likely to have.

(Remember, cache invalidation is one of the two hard problems).

A simplified example of this might the paid status of an invoice.  Your fulfillment system may need to know if invoice has been paid before it can release shipment.  Your billing system owns the decision that an invoice has been paid.  There's a small sliver of information shared between the two.

But the fulfillment systems copy of that data is subordinate -- the fulfillment system doesn't have the authority to *reject* a paid invoice.  (It may, of course, have the authority to raise exception reports "we can't meet the requirements of the purchase contract", or whatever).

Comment: As I said, a copy based on a readmodel is what I‘d going for. I‘m talking about duplicating data within different aggregates, not projections.

Comment: So am I.  There's no reason that one aggregate shouldn't hold a cached copy of data owned elsewhere.